# Flask saves an empty file

Tags: python, flask

My app is supposed to receive data from a user, save it locally and then send it Firebase storage. For some reason, even though the file gets successfully created where I want, I get an empty text file with no content. What am I doing wrong? Actually, I am following the official Flask tutorial.

```
if 'file' in request.files:
    photo = request.files['file']
    result = td.process(photo)
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket("<my-app>.com")
    blob = bucket.blob("demo")
    filename = secure_filename(photo.filename)
    #photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    photo.save("./" + filename)
    #f = open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename),"rb")
    #blob.upload_from_file(f)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: You might like to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660527/file-is-empty-after-saving-flask-uploads

Answer (score 3):

Do `photo.stream.seek(0)` before `photo.save("./" + filename)`.

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer solved it, therefore I voted up! The reason behind the solution for me was that I had read through the file before trying to save it. Then, the pointer was in a position where there was no more data and the file in the host machine was created, but empty.