# Uploading multiple files via enctype="multipart/form-data", the first file uploaded is always 0 in size, the rest are ok

Tags: python-3.x, forms, flask, python-requests

I am using a form enctype="multipart/form-data" and flask to upload multiple files to a server.

My problem is that the first file selected is always empty (0 size). All the rest files selected are uploaded with the right size, is just the first one selected that gets uploaded with a size of 0, making it unusable.

This looks related with the following question: [File is empty after saving flask uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660527/file-is-empty-after-saving-flask-uploads)

See the comment from bukman:

"I realized that flask has a habit of including one empty file upload with the exact same name and details as one of the file attachments(usually the first attachment) WHEN you use the 'multiple' attribute in your form"

Is that actually true? Because it seems to be exactly what is happening to me, and for me is a very weird way of behaving.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <table class="center">

      <tr>
          <td class="font-weight-bold" align="left">file.tcx:</td>
          <td class="font-weight-bold" align="left"><input type="file" 
           name="tcxfiles[]" multiple class="form-control-file"/></td>
      </tr>
   </table>


  <div style="text-align: center"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
   type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

And in Python / Flask I process the files this way:

```
files = request.files.getlist("tcxfiles[]")

        for each_file in files:
            if each_file and allowed_file(each_file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(each_file.filename)
                each_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

allowed_file is a function that I use just to filter the uplodaded files and allowing just .tcx files
secure_file_name function is a function to ensure the file name is safe.

Both copied from flask documentation:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

As mentioned, if I upload multiple files, the first file is stored with lenght 0, and the others with the right lenght.

If I select just one file, then it is stored with file 0.

My version of flask is 1.1.1

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('flask').version
'1.1.1'
```

Any tip will be useful, as I am scratching my head, trying to understand this behavior.

The expected results would be to have all the uploaded files with the right size, rather than having always one file with 0 size

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce with "hello world" attempt using Flask 1.1.1. Is there any more shaffolding around your code that isn't shown? Anything special about the files you select?

Comment: Thanks for checking Halvor. Files are nothing especial,   just some .tcx files from my own profile in Strava. Same for the code,  nothing hidden. Perhaps I can share in github

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce the scenario. I can upload multiple image files without any error.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── uploads
└── templates
    └── file_upload.html
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

`app.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'uploads')
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist("multiple_files[]")
        filenames = []
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                filenames.append(filename)
        flash("Uploaded files: {}".format(", ".join(filenames)))
    return render_template("file_upload.html")
```

`file_upload.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload Multiple Files</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
  <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
  <h1>Upload Multiple Files</h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action={{url_for("upload_file")}}>
    <input type="file" name="multiple_files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshots:**

Before uploading two images:

[image: before uploading]

After uploading two images:

[image: after uploading multiple files]

The `ls -l` indicates that the first file is not empty. I can view both images from `/static/uploads` folder.

Comment: Surprisingly I am not able to make it work, even when my code is pretty much the same. One thing that I have noticed when debugging is that the temporal file created under the folder: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp for the first file is 0 in size, while the other has the correct size.

Looks like the temporal uploaded file is already 0 in size?

I have the repository here: https://github.com/GonzaloMurillo/entrena

The files that I am using to test are under the folder tcx_files_examples/

Just if you want to test with the specific files. I am running this on a Windows 10  v1803

Comment: Can you create `upload` folder in `static` and check again?

Comment: It is created, just not uploaded to the repository.That is not the issue. If there is no folder, it simply fails..Here it uploads the first file with size 0,and the rest properly. Could this be a bug? Otherwise I cannot really understand whats going on here. Thanks for yourhelp so far!

Comment: I have pulled and run your code in a virtual environment. Although the code is similar to mine, it is uploading a blank file at first. But the code I have included in the answer is running properly, even with `tcx` format after adding it to `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS` list. TLDR: I could not find any problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts. Is amazing there must be an error in my code... but where and why? I keep researching

Comment: Still unable to explain this weird behavior, which is driving me crazy. Anyone else that can understand it?